# Java 1.7 or later is required to run Solr, but 1.8 Installed

Tags: java, solr

I can't start Solr 4.10.4 on Windows as it is stating:

> Java 1.7 or later is required to run Solr

Here is where it gets fun, I have Java JRE 1.8_102 already installed and if I type java -version in a command prompt it properly displays the Java version. If I try to launch on the next line using Solr.cmd -f, it gives me the error.

For another level of testing I dropped in Solr 5.1.0 and it starts without issue via Solr.cmd -f

Since it works in 5.1.0 and the Java version is correct, why doesn't it work with 4.10.4?

I have the JAVA_HOME environmental variables/paths and registry entries set correctly from what I can tell, or else Solr 5.1.0 wouldn't launch. (I point to the jre directory for HOME and the jre\bin for the Path).

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of Java installed. If Solr has it's own config file, you may have to specify the path for 1.8. I had a similar issue installing Spark the other day.

Comment: But why would it work for Solr 5.1.0 on the same box? These are fresh VMs without multiple Java, but I will double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up not being the Variable, but rather I was trying to start using Solr.cmd, where I needed to start Solr via browsing to example: java -jar start.jar. I am unsure why Solr.cmd won't work, but can work around it.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with 6.6.2 and the problem turned out to be a small bug in the solr.cmd script.

In the resolve_java_info subroutine it is doing a string compare rather than a numeric compare on the version. So editing this block of code:

```
REM Extract the major Java version, e.g. 7, 8, 9, 10 ...
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("!JAVA_VERSION_INFO!") do (
  if "%%a" GEQ "9" (
    set JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=%%a
  ) else (
    set JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=%%b
  )
)
```

and changing

```
  if "%%a" GEQ "9" (
```

to:

```
  if %%a GEQ 9 (
```

by removing the quotes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Look at the `bin\solr.cmd` script.

That is where the Solr figures out which JVM to use.  It is also where that error message comes from.  (https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_4x/solr/bin/solr.cmd)

The relevant section is this (or similar):

```
REM Verify Java is available
if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto need_java_home
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version:1.8 -version > nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 "%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version:1.7 -version > nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto need_java_vers
set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
```

It looks to me as if the problem is that your `%JAVA_HOME%` is *not* set correctly.

> Since it works in 5.1.0 and the Java version is correct, why doesn't it work with 4.10.4?

The `solr.cmd` script was rewritten in Solr 5.x.  Compare the two versions that you have installed.

Comment: *"The JAVA_HOME has been set to jre\bin"* -  That's your mistake!!  It should NOT be set to the jre\bin OR bin.  It should be set to the JRE or JDK installation directory.  Look at the "cmd" file and what it is doing.

Comment: I mistyped. The JAVA_HOME has always been set to jre not the bin. So it is set correctly.

Comment: Either way, as you can see it is the setting of %JAVA_HOME% *that the `solr.cmd` script sees* that matters.  If the script is printing that message, and you do have Java 7 (or greater) installed, then that is **proof** that the setting it is incorrect.  Somehow.  Now, I cannot look over your shoulder and tell you exactly what you are doing wrong.  But you **are** doing something wrong.  An it **is** that variable setting.

Comment: I have tried every combination of variables, and while I can get Java -Version to recognize 1.8, Solr still throws the 1.7 or later message. Any other ideas?

Comment: It ended up not being a variable. It was not starting properly, as I was trying to launch via solr.cmd, where in 4.10.4 I needed to use java -jar start.jar

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below fix, and it is worked.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-12141

patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12916463/12916463_SOLR-12141.patch

Comment: Can we copy the fix into the answer? If the link is made redundant so does this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have installed Java 10.0.2 and I got the error
**Error:Java 1.7 or later is required to run Solr, but 1.8 Installed**

I have checked the code and the printed the variable **JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION**, which is always set to 0, then I changed the line

```
REM Extract the major Java version, e.g. 7, 8, 9, 10 ...
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%a in ("!JAVA_VERSION_INFO!") do (
     set JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=%%a
  )
```

to

```
REM Extract the major Java version, e.g. 7, 8, 9, 10 ...
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("!JAVA_VERSION_INFO!") do (
     set JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=%%a
  )
```

*Note: tokens is changed*

For my case it worked. in case if it didn't help you, you can debug solr.cmd a little. :)